# Create an array of consecutive numbers from 1 to n in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to code a function that will make an array of consecutive numbers from `1` up to a number `n`. For example, I would expect `array[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`. My code doesn't seem to be running but I don't exactly know why.

```
int count (int a)
{
   scanf("%d", &a);
   int i;
   int array[a];
   do
   {
      i = 0;
      a = a - i;
      array[a - 1] = a;
      i++;
   }
   while (a > 0);
   printf("Resulting array is %d", array[a]);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are setting your `i` to `0` in *each* iteration.

Comment: Surely the `i = 0`should go outside the loop, no?

Comment: Rest of the logic is weird too.

Comment: Why are you taking `a` as a parameter if you just overwrite it in the first line with `scanf` anyway?

Comment: oh that's so helpful! I put it outside the loop, and while the code still isn't working, I think I'm heading in the right direction!

Comment: Index starts with 0 so if you add 0 to your array, everything will be normal. array[11] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Comment: @Oguz: That will certainly give you an "excess elements in initializer" warning. `:)` (Plus you can't initialize VLAs.)

Comment: Ugh, you are definitely right. I corrected it. :)

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/GnQB5U)

Answer (score 4):

An idiomatic C way would be to define a function that *fills* an existing array:

```
void count(int *array, int max)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < max; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = i+1;
    }
}
```

You can call it e.g. like this:

```
int arr[10];
count(arr, 10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a for loop to create your array.

```
int i;
int array[a];
for(i = 0; i < a; i++) {
  array[i] = i + 1;
}

return 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `do while` loop could simply be replaced by the following `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
  array[i] = i + 1;
```

Similarly, for displaying each element in `array`, you can iterate over the elements of `array` by means of a `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++) 
  printf("Element at %2d is %d\n", i, array[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the print statement

```
 printf("Resulting array is %d", array[a]);
```

is wrong!! That's not how you print an array. You need to loop over the index, get the individual elements and print them.

Moreover, when you try using `array[a]`, think of the value for `a`. That's surely *not* what you want.

That said, there are other issues, like setting `i` to `0` in each iteration of `do...while` loop. That will lose the previously calculated value and start over. Move the initial assignment outside the loop body.

A slightly modified version, follow the comments

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int count (void)                 // no need for parameter if you're asking user for size
{
   int size = 0;                 //define size
   int ret = scanf("%d", &size); //read it

   if ( (ret != 1) || ( size < 1) ) return -1;      //error check

   int i = 0;                    //initialize local variables

   int array[size];              //note: this is VLA

   do
   {
       array[i] = i+1;           //start populating elements
       i++;
   }
   while (size > i);             //go on unless you've reached the given size

   puts ("Resulting array is");   // start printing ....

   for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
   {
       printf("%d\t", array[i]);   //...them one by one
   }

   return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    (void)count();  //call the function
}
```

Comment: If the entered size is 0, you'll write past the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int* count(int a)
{
   int array[a];
   for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
   {
      array[i] = i + 1;
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i)
   {
      printf("%d, ", i + 1);
   }
   return array;
}
```

Comment: I think it would be best if the logic from printing was separated from the logic of generation the array.

Comment: `return array;` ?

Comment: This is just wrong, the pointer returned will be meaningless and trying to use it will be **undefined behavior**.

Comment: And that's not the signature of the original function anyway

Comment: Well, creating an array inside a function, then not using or returning it, seems somewhat unnecessary...

Comment: int array[a]; won't compile everywhere so i think using malloc is better

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto still you can't return it: returning arrays in C is not possible, a pointer will be returned instead. And as it has *automatic* storage duration, it's **gone** after your function exits, so the pointer doesn't point to anything usable (it's an invalid pointer).

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto there are several ways around this, the **worst** would be to give the array *static* storage duration by writing a `static` in front of the declaration. Then it lives for the whole execution time. but that means there's only one instance ever, so calling the function again modifies the same array. Threading will lead to concurrent accesses.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto the idiomatic C way is to let the caller provide the array and only write to it (you need a means to pass the size to the function for this to work)

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto the last option is to create the array with `malloc()`, this must be explicitly `free()`d when done, so the caller has to eventually call `free()` on it.

Comment: @Felix Palmen isn't the malloc the right way to do it here since what he have done won't compile everywhere

Comment: ...but maybe the array is needed only in the context of this function? In this case it's ok to use a local variable and throw it away on exit. IMHO we're thinking too much about a silly example...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple "for" loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
    array [i] = i + 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't really need the `a` parameter. You can use a local
- the `do,while` is broken because you set `i` to `0` at each iteration and its overly complicated. You can achieve the same result in a much easier way. An element at location `i` has to have value `i+1`, easy as it sounds.
- You have to loop over the element of the array to print them all. A single `printf` prints only `1` element of the array. If you want them all, then you have to iterate over all of them.

What about something like the following?

```
void count(){
   int a,i=0;
   scanf("%d", &a);
   int array[a];
   while(i<a){
    array[i]=i+1;
    i++
   }

   //now print it
   i=0;
   while(i<a)
    printf(" %d ", array[i++]);

}
```

---

As an aside, note that you are using VLAs. That means there's a limit on the size of the array you can create which depends on your machine+compiler.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few bugs here . One that if you are accepting 'a' as a arg to function , why are you scanning it then. It just over writes the value you collected. Two the way you are trying to print the array is wrong as specified above and you should use a loop.  Three , you can save a few lines like ,

```
for(int i =0; i<a ; i++) 
{ 
arr[i]=i+1;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to code a function that will make an array of consecutive
>   numbers from 1 up to a number n.

In C++ there is already such a function that is named `iota` and declared in the header `<numeric>`.

In C such a function can look the following way

```
void iota(int a[], size_t n, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = value++;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void iota(int a[], size_t n, int value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) a[i] = value++;
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 1;

    scanf( "%zu", &n );

    int a[n];

    iota( a, n, 1 );

    for ( size_t i =0; i < n; i++ ) printf( "%d ", a[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter `10` then the output will look like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

As for your program then in this loop

```
do
{
    i = 0;
    a = a - i;
    array[a - 1] = a;
    i++;
}
while (a > 0);
```

the variable `a` is not being changed because in the beginning of each iteration the variable `i` is set to 0.

You could write the loop like

```
i = 0;
do
{
    array[a - i - 1] = a - i;
    i++;
} while ( i != a );
```

Take into account that this statement

```
printf("Resulting array is %d", array[a]);
```

does not make sense. If you are going to output an array element by element you have to use a loop as for example it is shown in the demonstrative program above.